# 1999 Katana 750 will not start

Tags: electrical, starting, katana

Rode it today ran fine. Come back home and I stalled it. 20 minutes later I turn the key to ride it again and nothing. I have no lights of any sort.

I did check the fuses and they seem ok. What else should I try?

Comment: This seems to be your first posting here.  Welcome.  I will say generally folks leave a bit more detail on what they've tried. Have you reviewed [the electrical schematic for your bike?](http://www.carlsalter.com/pdfs/Suzuki_GSX750F_Wiring_Diagram.jpg)  Do you have access to a multimeter?  Check that same site to get the complete service manual for your bike.  I'm guessing there is a guide in there that tells you what component is what on that diagram.

Comment: Do you know where are all the fuses are?   Did you test your battery?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to check all of the safety features that were included on the bike.  Kickstand up, in neutral, clutch in, kill switch set to run, and key on.

Comment: Charged the battery over the night and now the lights turn on and starts. Thanks pointing me in the right direction though